# Qual é a influência do Nheengatu no idioma Português?

Tags: ortografia, pronúncia, origem-histórica, linguística, português-brasileiro

A língua nativa [Nheengatu](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nheengatu) pertence à família linguística tupi-guarani. Foi usada não apenas por índios e jesuítas, mas também como língua corrente de muitos colonos de sangue português. O Nheengatu ainda é falado por cerca de 8 000 pessoas entre Brasil, Colômbia e Venezuela.

Qual é a influência do Nheengatu no idioma Português?
Quais seriam algumas palavras e pronuncias derivadas do Nheengatu?
Essa influência ocorreu só no Brasil?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O que significa, neste contexto, "influência"?

É fácil ver que um grande número de vocábulos, particularmente nomes de plantas e de animais, foi tomada de empréstimo ao tupi pelo português: arara, mandioca, perereca, jaguatirica, taquara, gravatá, tapera, murundu, pereba. Se isso conta como influência, então é uma influência considerável. Segundo a professora Ana Suelly Cabral, cerca de 80% dos nomes de bichos e plantas que não foram importados do Velho Mundo são de origem tupi.

Já quanto à fonética, é bem mais difícil emitir uma opinião. É famosa a tese de que o "r" retroflexo característico dos falares do interior de São Paulo e sul de Minas Gerais se deve a uma "influência" do Tupi. Mas é difícil distinguir o que é influência de uma outra língua do que é deriva linguística própria do português, e é notável a ausência de outros empréstimos fonéticos (não restam sinais do /mb/, /nd/, /ng/ iniciais (mboitata virou boitatá), do /ts/, da oclusão glotal, ou do ü semelhante ao u francês. Em todos os empréstimos léxicos, a fonética do tupi foi adaptada ao português; por que supor que a pronuncia caipira de uma palavra inequivocamente portuguesa como "parecer" seria determinada pelo tupi?). Outra ideia corrente é a de que o sotaque característico do Brasil se deve à influência tupi (mas esta é ainda mais duvidosa, sendo mais provável que o português brasileiro seja mais conservador, foneticamente, do que o português europeu). Da mesma forma, as supostas influências gramaticais (queda da desinência de plural dos substantivos quando precedidos de artigo, preferência pela próclise em vez da ênclise, e, sobretudo, preferência pelo gerúndio em vez de a+infinitivo - que é muito mais provavelmente um traço conservador da gramática brasileira) parecem ser fantasiosas.

Answer (score 2):

É possível saber mais no livro [Livro Religião como tradução : missionarios, Tupi e "Tapuia" no Brasil colonial](http://www.bibliotecadigital.unicamp.br/document/?code=vtls000220275) mas o Nheengatu não é o tupi antigo, sim o que se chamava *Língua Geral*, ou seja, uma aculturação do tupi com base na cultura Europeia trazida pelos colonos e pelos Jesuítas.

Um exemplo interessante citado no livro acima e também no "Religião dos Tupinambás" do Alfred Métraux é **Tupã**.

A maioria das pessoas acredita que Tupã é o deus dos índios. Não é e isto porque os índios não tinham o conceito de divindade logo não podiam ter um deus. Tupã foi criado pelos Jesuítas para aculturar os índios quanto à noção de divino.

Tupã é um exemplo de vocábulo Nheengatu mas há muitos outros.

Agora, pela sua pergunta, eu deduzo que você esteja falando sobre o tupi antigo que não é o Nheengatu. As duas línguas são muito parecidas. No fundo o Nheengatu é o tupi aculturado, partilhado entre as duas culturas.

As palavras indígenas: mandioca, piranha, Tijuca, babaca, arara são todas oriundas do Nheengatu que, por sua vez, vem do tupi antigo.

O tupi era falado por toda a família Tupinambá, que se estendia desde o Nordeste brasileiro até o Paraguai e, creio, a Argentina embora aí já se juntasse com os guaranis. Isso para dizer que o Nheengatu era falado em toda essa região.